# CCString deprecated in Cocos2D-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

It seems that CCString is deprecated in Cocos2d-x v3.5. What should we use instead? Also, what is the reason for the deprecation?

Comment: [Value](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/dc/dd1/classcocos2d_1_1_value.html) is the type that can be used as a container for strings etc. but I am not aware of any particular reasons of this deprecation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: use std::string instead.

The entire codebase is moving toward using the standard library (STL, std:: namespace) where it makes sense as well as new c++11 features.

You can continue to use CCString anywhere you are using CCArray and CCDictionary. These are all deprecated, of course, so you should eventually move to using std::string.

ValueMap, and ValueVector are the replacements for CCArray and CCDictionary that are based on the STL std::map and std::vector and which contain Value objects. Value can hold std::string, int, float, bool, as well as ValueMap/ValueVector to allow for nested containers.

Comment: Why CCImage is also deprecated?

Comment: Use Image instead. Essentially most classes (or maybe all with 3.8) have the CC prefix removed in favor of them being inside the cocos2d:: namespace hierarchy.
See deprecated/CCDeprecated.h for all of these changes.

Comment: Using std::string instead of CCString is fine. But on the topic of removing CC* in CCImage and all those others used-to-be CC-classes, I just find it harder to find the cocos class I need... when I need it. Am I the only one using code completion? Well, not meaning to start a long discussion - I can handle as is :-). But FWIW, at least they could have renamed those classes to something else like CXImage etc.

Comment: If they wanted a prefix they'd have just kept CC. Essentially it's more c++ style to use a namespace instead. You could alias the cocos2d namespace to cc and then write cc:: to get the list of possible completions.   I guess I haven't noticed the missing CC and actually prefer just writing Sprite instead of CCSprite. Personal pref I guess. Note they're just deprecated so you can still use CCSprite. Also, you can always alias any type with `using CCSprite = cocos2d::Sprite;`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to upgrade your app from 2.x to 3.x.
Use __String instead.

Otherwise, use std::string as the answer above.